# Lightning Component that requires attachemnts

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, case, attachment, aura

We have a communities page (displayed below) that has a Create Case From for the community user to create cases based on picklist values that are dependent on each other. The Request Type picklist values are dependent on Request Category, Request Category picklist values are dependent on Department and so forth). They are all required fields (including Description) except for the Sub Type due to only applying for certain Request Types. So we have the following “Request Categories” picklist values:

Account Setup
Forms/Docs

Restrictions
Account Update

We would like an attachment to be required for “Account Setup” and “Form/Docs” and not required for “Restrictions” and “Account Update”. I was informed that in order to do that, I would need to build a Lightning Component (which includes an aura controller and an aura app) that requires the attachment based on the selection the community user makes, and that displays an alert "Attachment required" if the there are no attachments for the aforementioned Request Categories. I am brand new to Lightning components. Any assistance in coding this would be much appreciated [image: Case Form]